# Running C++ Redistributable files from a Probing Folder

Tags: c#, c++, dll, redistributable, probing

I'm currently having an issue with "Probing" dlls from another folder. Specifically the C++ Redistributable files that my application is dependent on and that I have just included in my folder to avoid having to run an installer.

The application runs successfully if these files are in the same folder as the exe:

- msvcp110.dll
- msvcp120.dll
- msvcp140.dll
- msvcr110.dll
- msvcr120.dll
- vcruntime140.dll

However when I in my App.config of my application try to probe dlls to 2 other folders, none of them is loaded upon execution of the .exe.

```
<probing privatePath="DataResources/cefsharp;DataResources/miscellaneous" />
```

The DLLS are located in the `DataResources/miscellaneous` folder. The DLLS from `DataResources/cefsharp` (which are some of my other dlls) ARE loaded however.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?
Thank you very much!

Comment: The operating system needs to find these DLLs, so the probing element plays no role at all since that only affects the CLR.  The OS looks in the same directory as the EXE, the Windows directories, the directories listed in the PATH environment variable and the directory specified by SetDllDirectory().  Pick your poison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that when it comes to these files, CefSharp is dependent on them being in the exact same folder as the CefSharp files themself. In my case, moving these files to the CefSharp folder did the trick.

This is probably not the case in others circumstances but if you are using CefSharp are having this same exact problem, that's why.